# What is the cause of Error: Call to undefined function civicrmVersion() in sparkpost_civicrm_check()

Tags: sparkpost, 5.1.0

Drupal 7.59 Civi 5.1.2 PHP 7 MariaDB 10.1 Debian 9

If our users access "example.com/civicrm" without first logging into Drupal, they receive a generic white page with the message "Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.", but also with a green drupal message saying "Log in successful for ...."

Upon refreshing the page, users can then access Civi normally.

Just one php error in the recent log messages:-

> Error: Call to undefined function civicrmVersion() in
>   sparkpost_civicrm_check() (line 145 of
>   /var/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/sparkpost.php).

Could anyone advise the fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: Sparkpost version is 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on the github issue list: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/pull/58/commits/69a0bdb17bb520334da7f472a2d7670b44da8071

Applied the commit and it has resolved the problem.